# Twitter + OAuth Problem -- Cancel Button

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth

I'm implementing OAuth to post on Twitter... which works perfectly. My issue is for those who entered the Twitter login area by accident and want to press the "Cancel" button. Unfortunately, the "Cancel" button is dismissed but then immediately reappears.

Here is the code for the "Cancel" button:

```
- (void)cancel:(id)sender {
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(OAuthTwitterControllerCanceled:)]) [_delegate OAuthTwitterControllerCanceled: self];
    [self performSelector: @selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) withObject: (id) kCFBooleanTrue afterDelay: 0.0];
}
```

I think what I need to do is put the right code in the `viewDidDisappear` area... the problem is I don't know what code to put in.

Any help would be great! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely not with the cancel button and the way it is handled, but in the way you call the code to post to twitter the first (and second) time.  Place a break point in the line where you instantiate the twitter posting process, and see why it is being triggered a second time by inspecting the stack trace when it does break.

Comment: This error occurs before a post is even sent. Does that matter? Or is it when Twitter is first called?

Comment: you must have code that triggers the popup. place your breakpoint there.

Comment: Thanks coneybeare... I'll try that in a bit.

Comment: That is exactly what is happening... what's the best way to tackle this?

Comment: I found someone else who had the same problem... and this is how they fixed it "Just write code of viewdidappear to twitter update button…and in viewdidappear write functionality of back button." What back button code works in this situation?

Comment: read the stack trace to see what is calling it the second time, then eliminate it.

Comment: Sorry to sound like a noob... but where do I inspect the stack trace? Is it part of Instruments?

Comment: when you run the app, press shift-cmd-y to bring up the debugger.  When a breakpoint is reached, you will be able to see the functions that led up to the call in the stack trace on the left side of the debugger.

Comment: Thanks! All figured out. It was the way I called it in viewDidAppear.